# Orbit of group action on $e_1$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I'm working on the orbit of $e_1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the action of matrix multiplication. For some matrix $A$ in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, I believe that the orbit is simply any vector $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not the zero vector. This seems obvious, but is it necessary to prove that any such vector is in the orbit? If so, how would I do that?

Then, what if I'm working with some matrix $A$ in the orthogonal group $O_2$ instead? Beyond writing down the definition of $O_2$, I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: If you can't find a way to prove it, why is it "obvious"? Hint: given any nonzero vector $v$, construct a matrix whose first column is $v$, and whose second column is such that the determinant is $1$. For the orthogonal group, a similar argument along with Gram-Schmidt shows that the orbit is the set of vectors of the same length as your initial vector (the unit circle in the case of $e_1$).

Comment: Please use MathJax. When you write R2 do you mean $R^2$? What is e1? Please include only one question in a post.

Answer (score 1):

The case of $\operatorname{SL}(2, \Bbb R)$ is not *obvious*, inasmuch as the statement is not true for other common matrix groups, including $\operatorname{O}(2, \Bbb R)$.

**Hint** Recall that for any matrix $A \in M(2, \Bbb R)$, the image $A {\bf e}_1$ of the first standard basis vector ${\bf e}_1 := \pmatrix{1\\0}$ under the standard action of $A$ is just the first column of $A$. So, your claim is equivalent to the statement that for any nonzero vector $\pmatrix{a\\b} \in \Bbb R^2$ there is a matrix in $\operatorname{SL}(2, \Bbb R)$ of the form $\pmatrix{a&\ast\\b&\ast}$.

Comment: I see, so how would I go about finding the correct orbit?

Comment: Put another way, the orbit of ${\bf e}_1$ under any matrix group $G$ is precisely the set of first columns of elements of $G$.